# How can I add "proper" images (not Icons) to my JFrame/JPanel/JComponents (Swing) (Kotlin)

Tags: image, swing, kotlin, jcomponent

Language: Kotlin,
GUI Library: Swing,
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA

I know that there are similarly phrased questions, but note that I want to add multiple images, not just one, to any type of JComponent that holds other components. For example, I am not concerned with adding an image to a JLabel, I already know how to do that. I want to know how to add an image to a JFrame, JPanel, Container, etc.; all things that hold other Components (and have an add(Component) function). Finally, I don't want that workaround where you add the image to a JLabel with no text and then add that to the container. I would like to just use the Image class or a subset like BufferedImage or URL.

I want to be able to call the add() method from the Container class, jFrame.add(component) for example, where component is some sort of image. I want this to result in an image being displayed on the screen.
The ImageIcon class is not a Component so this can't be input on its own. I think I would have to create some sort of custom Image class that extends from Component or JComponent, but I don't know what I would have to override to get that to display an image on screen when added to another JComponent. There are multiple solutions to this, but to clarify, I don't want some kind of "middle man" where I add a JLabel or JButton or something that only contains an Icon. I don't want to display icons anyway, I want to display full-sized images anywhere on the screen. I will provide a possible example of what I want the final result to look like.

```
class MyApp() {

    fun init() {
        var jFrame = JFrame()
        jFrame.add(Image("filepath/image.png"))
        //Some other JFrame boiler plate
        jFrame.isVisible = true
    }

}

fun main() {
    MyApp().init()
}
```

The unclear part is the Image class, and whether that's a custom class that inherits JImage, or some already defined class or method I don't know about. I know about ImageIO and BufferedImage and ImageIcon, but none of them directly go into this method, as they don't inherit Component or JComponent.

EDIT:

I tried using Camickr's second solution, but it didn't work. I will post the code to see if a made a simple mistake.

```
import java.awt.Image as AWTImage
import java.awt.Image.*
//Including these imports as I used name alias so I had to say what it was from.

open class JImage(var point: Point = Point(0, 0), image: AWTImage): JComponent() {
    var image: ImageIcon = ImageIcon(image)

    override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics?) {
        super.paint(g)
        g?.drawImage(image.image, point.x.toInt(), point.y.toInt(), null)
    }
}

class SplashScreen(image: JImage): Frame() {

    init {
        //jFrame.isUndecorated = true
        jFrame.add(image)
    }
}

class MyApp {

    fun init() {
        var jFrame = SplashScreen(JImage(image = ImageIO.read(Loader().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/images/splashscreen/SplashScreen.png"))).getScaledInstance(Size(1000, 1000*3/5)))
        jFrame.isVisible = true
    }
}

fun main() {
    MyApp().init()
}
```

FINAL EDIT:

Okay, so I did make a simple mistake when trying this solution. I overrode paintComponent() but then inside it, I called super.paint(). Additionally, I realized I didn't have to use the ImageIcon class, which I didn't want to do anyway. This is the Image class I have come up with.

```
open class JImage(var point: Point = Point(0, 0), var image: AWTImage): JComponent() {

    fun getScaledInstance(size: Size, scalingMethods: ScalingMethods = ScalingMethods.DEFAULT): JImage {
        val scale: Int = when(scalingMethods) {
            ScalingMethods.DEFAULT -> SCALE_DEFAULT
            ScalingMethods.FAST -> SCALE_FAST
            ScalingMethods.AREA_AVERAGING -> SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING
            ScalingMethods.REPLICATE -> SCALE_REPLICATE
            ScalingMethods.SMOOTH -> SCALE_SMOOTH
        }
        return JImage(point, image.getScaledInstance(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt(), scale))
    }

    override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics?) {
        super.paintComponent(g)
        g?.drawImage(image, point.x.toInt(), point.y.toInt(), null)
    }
}
```

Comment: *so I did make a simple mistake when trying this solution.* - and that is the reason I suggested you start with the working example and then customize it. *I realized I didn't have to use the ImageIcon class, which I didn't want to do anyway.* - as I suggested you needed to use the drawImage(…) class which takes a `Image` as a parameter so I don't know why you think you needed to use an ImageIcon. You said you already new about the ImageIo and BufferedImage classes, so I assumed you would use thos methods to create the image you wanted to paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how to add an image to a JFrame, JPanel, Container, etc.

You don't add an image to a JFrame, JPanel etc. As you said an image is not a component. You add the image to a JLabel and add the label to the panel. This is the easiest and more direct way to display an image at its actual size.

Don't know if Kotlin is any different, but the other option is to do custom painting and paint the image on a `JPanel` by overriding the `paintComponent(…)` method and using the `Graphics.drawImage(…)` method and then add the panel to the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for painting basics.

You can also check out [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for an example that paints an image as a background of the panel. The image can be:

1. painted at its real size
2. scaled to fill the panel
3. tiled to fill the panel
   Just note that the image should NOT be read in the paintComponent() method as painting code should be efficient.

Comment: Override paintComponent() from where? On what object? Please provide some example code. I made an Image class that inherits from the JComponent class and when I added it to my frame I got "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.getComponentGraphics(JComponent.java:750)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1019)
 at boundary.swing.JImage.paintComponent(JImage.kt:28) followed by at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
 at boundary.swing.JImage.paintComponent(JImage.kt:28) repeated forever

Comment: *On what object?* Already answered. I added highlighting for emphasis. *Please provide some example code*  - I did provide example code: 1) I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial for the basics and 2) a complete working example is found in the Background Panel example. Did you download either of the demo code found in the links? Post your [mre] based on the code found in the Custom Painting tutorial if you have questions. As I stated I have no idea if the code is different in Kotlin, so the first thing to do is test the demo code to see if it works and then customize that code..

Comment: *I made an Image class that inherits from the JComponent* - that should also work.

Comment: My image class didn't work because I didn't know what to put in the image class. Otherwise, I wouldn't have needed to upload this question. When I ran it, nothing showed up on the screen. I tried his custom pain method in it and it didn't work. I will post my code that does this, but again, it doesn't currently work.

Comment: I will accept this answer, as it did have a solution that worked for me in there **somewhere** but it mostly pertained of using a method I already said in the question I was trying to avoid. Anyways, apart from that, thanks!

Comment: *it mostly pertained of using a method I already said in the question I was trying to avoid.* - just because you want to avoid something doesn't mean you can. That is NOT the way Swing is designed to work. You must work with components to display an image. That is the way every Swing component works. You create a component and do custom painting to represent the functionality of that component. So you can't Just call a class JImage and expect it to magically be a component that you can add to the frame. You actually have to make it a component.

Comment: Oh I think you misunderstood, the method that I said I didn't want to use was adding an image to a JLabel. Your method of implementing JComponent is what I ended up using. I overrode the paintComponent method and it displayed on the screen. Your background panel example added an image to a JLabel and that is what you suggested at the top of your response. **That** is what I didn't want to use. I know I have to use components in **some** way, I just strictly didn't want to use a JLabel.